# Python adding a string after range

Tags: python, python-3.x

a little stuck on this function.

- So N = 5 it will print 0 1 2 3 4
- N = 3 it will print 0 1 2

I was able to get this to run but on second step I need to add the results together. So it would be

- N=3 0+1+2 = 3
- N=5 0+1+2+3+4 = 10

Below is my code I am just unsure how to structure this to get the results I seek.

```
n = int(input("n = "))
if i in range(n):
    x = str(i)
    print(sum(x))

n = 5
```

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
File "<ipython-input-17-95a1e729596f>", line 4, in <module>
    print(sum(x))

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

Comment: Could you please format your code?

Comment: `x = str(i)` now x is a string. Summing a string cannot be done using `sum`

Comment: Why are you converting to a string???

Comment: As an int I cannot make add each individual number so I thought making it a string would allow me too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't really use the built-in `sum()` function in a `for-loop` to add up the numbers in that `range`. You can either forget the loop altogether or add to a variable (`s`):

```
n = int(input("n = "))
s = 0
for i in range(n):
    s += i
    print(s)
```

So when I enter `n = 5`, the output is the sums:

```
0
1
3
6
10
```

---

As stated at the beginning of this post, I mentioned that you could do this without using a `loop`. So, here is how you would do that:

```
n = int(input("n = "))
print(sum(range(n))
```

which when `n = 5` would just `print` the total sum of `10`.

---

Oh and one last note is that you don't need to convert an integer (the `i` in the `for-loop`) to a `string` to be able to `print` it.

Comment: this makes sense to be yields a result of 0

Comment: @sypher5 Sorry, please explain further, this produces the right output for me

Comment: No I am sorry for some reason had an if rather than for in the code. I am just debating what may work best for my next step in the process

Comment: @sypher5 Please accept (grey --> green tick next to answer) then as it works!

Answer (score 0):

I'd keep it simple, avoid the loop, and use the resources Python gives you:

```
n = int(input("n = "))

print(*range(n), sep=' + ', end=' = ')
print(sum(range(n)))
```

USAGE

```
% python3 test.py
n = 5
0 + 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 = 10
%
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can just do the following.

First, ask for the input, and translate the given number from string to integer.

```
n = int(input("N = "))
```

Then, print a sum of the range from 0 to n-1.

```
print(sum(range(n)))
```

Hope it is what you were asking!

Comment: What's the `list()` doing in there?  Should work fine without it.  See previous answers for an example without it.